# windbind NT_STATUS_INVALID_COMPUTER_NAME

Tags: windows, samba, active-directory

I'm tryng to join an Active Directory server with centOS. I started `authconfig-tui`, then I run `net join -w univ-tours -S x.x.x.x -U xxxx@univ-tours`.

I get the following message:

```
Error in domain join verification (credential setup failed):
NT_STATUS_INVALID_COMPUTER_NAME
Unable to join domain UNIV-TOURS.
```

my computer name is `rcluster.univ-tours.local`. Should I change it?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have sufficient privileges to join the domain...